# How can I stop documents in a workflow being amended or replaced?

Tags: workflow

I want to ensure that the document approved in workflow cannot be amended either during or after workflow.  I have tried makeing the document read only and putting it on a read only drive but still someone needs to have access to put it on the drive and could easily amend or replace the document with an unapproved version.

Any ideas for how to stop a document being changed once approved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nikki,

One way is you can use [these custom activities](http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/) for SharePoint Designer workflow...

Here you will have Actions like Grant Permission on Item etc, and you can set up a SharePoint Group which just has Read permissions and give the Item this group...

I hope this helps!

Arsalan Adam Khatri
Blog: http://arsalkhatri.wordpress.com